# HTML form submission with special characters

Tags: html

I am trying to submit a form field whose value is Transaction ID - sample . When the date gets submitted the value is Transaction ID ? sample

How do I get rid of the ?

I used HTML special codes for dash/long dash/short dash but still value gets submitted as ?

Please help

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? This way we may have an idea as to what your stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure that all input characters get sent correctly is to use UTF-8 character encoding for the form data. This happens automatically if the page containing the form is UTF-8 encoded (and declared to be that); otherwise, use the parameter `accept-charset=utf-8` in the form data.

Naturally, you form handler must then be prepared to handling UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: I tried <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="example.com" method="POST" id="sample" class="sample" accept-charset="UTF-8"> but still does not work and the weird part is the changes do not even show up in the view source

Comment: @htmlquery, it seems that you are using some authoring environment where your changes do not affect the code sent to browsers. It is impossible to help you without more information.

Comment: Yes I am using Expression engine CMS